# Handle back key when the last fragment is popped

Tags: android, android-fragments

I add `Fragments` to my `Activity` dynamically based on user interaction. When I press the back key, the fragments are popped. However when I press the back key for the fragment which was first added to the stack, the 'Activity' shows an empty layout. I would like the Activity to call `finish()' at this point and disappear. I've tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()==0){
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But this has the effect of blocking the back key functionality. Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the second `return true;` to `return false;` to indicate that you did NOT handle the keypress. This should close the activity when the back stack is empty, and leave it as is otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Where are you adding your very first fragment?  Don't add that transaction to the back stack it should work the way you want it.

Comment: simple and effective. works just the way i wanted it to. thanks!